# Почему не работает программа, выдает ошибку index out of range

Tags: python, алгоритм

Вводится 5 строк. Вывести слова в алфавитном порядке.

```
s = [input () for i in range (5)]
def quicksort (s):
    pivot = s[0]
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s

    less = [i for i in s[1:] if i <= pivot]
    greater = [i for i in s[1:] if i > pivot]
    return quicksort (less) + [pivot] + quicksort (greater)

print (quicksort (s))
```

Comment: Не нужно исправлять код в вопросе после того, как получили правильный ответ - это может затруднить людям с похожей проблемой получить пользу от вашего вопроса. Если у вас появилась другая проблема - создайте ещё один вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что проверку следует делать ДО обращения к элементу списка (т.к. элемента может и не быть)

```py
if len(s) == 1:
    return s
pivot = s[0]
```

---

Также в функцию может прийти пустой список, поэтому необходимо ещё добавить проверку этого

```py
if len(s) == 1 or len(s) == 0:
    return s
```